# Does apache httpcore 4.3.2 support Java 8?

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

I'm trying migrate web project to Java 8. 
The project uses the library apache httpclient 4.3.2 as dependency, but the httpclient documentation doesn't specify whether it supports Java 8. 
Does any documentation exists where indicate httpcore 4.3.* support Java 8?